# Using an OnCalcField with a query

Tags: mysql, delphi, firedac

```
  // accounts receivable
 qAR.SQL.Clear;
 qAR.SQL.Text := 'Select C.Lastname,C.Firstname,C.Address,C.City,C.State,C.Zip,' +
                 'C.Hercell,C.Hiscell,C.Phone,C.Code,' +
                 'I.Date,I.Clino,I.Date,I.ToBePaid,' +
                 'SUM(CASE when C.Clino = I.Clino then I.ToBePaid END) as nToBePaid,' +
                 'SUM(CASE when C.Clino = I.Clino and I.Date between :S0 and :E0 then I.ToBePaid END) as nCurrent,' +
                 'SUM(CASE when C.Clino = I.Clino and I.Date between :S1 and :E1 then I.ToBePaid END) as nOver30,' +
                 'SUM(CASE when C.Clino = I.Clino and I.Date between :S2 and :E2 then I.ToBePaid END) as nOver60,' +
                 'SUM(CASE when C.Clino = I.Clino and I.Date <= :E3 then I.ToBePaid END) as nOver90 ' +
                 'from Invoice I ' +
                 'join Client C on C.Clino = I.Clino ' +
                 'where I.Date <= :E ' +
                 'and I.ToBePaid <> 0 ' +
                 'and I.Active = true ' +
                 'and C.Code <> 1 ' +
                 'group by C.Clino ' +
                 'having nToBePaid > 0 ' +
                 'order by C.Lastname,C.Firstname';
 qAR.ParamByName('S0').AsDate := dDate30 + 1;
 qAR.ParamByName('E0').AsDate := dBillingDate;
 qAR.ParamByName('S1').AsDate := dDate60 + 1;
 qAR.ParamByName('E1').AsDate := dDate30;
 qAR.ParamByName('S2').AsDate := dDate90 + 1;
 qAR.ParamByName('E2').AsDate := dDate60;
 qAR.ParamByName('E3').AsDate := dDate90;
 qAR.ParamByName('E').AsDate := dBillingDate;
 qAR.FieldDefs.Updated := false;
 qAR.FieldDefs.Update;
 oField := TBooleanField.Create( qAR );
 oField.FieldKind := fkCalculated;
 qAR.OnCalcFields := qARCalcFields;
 qAR.DetailFields := 'Clino';
 qAR.Open;
```

I have a calculated field `Sel` (boolean) define in this query.  I want to click a button and have the `Sel` fields on all records to be set to `TRUE` and another button and have them all set to `FALSE`.  What should the code of `1) the OnCalcField`  and `2) each of the buttons` be?

Thanks,
Jim Sawyer

Comment: I cant see the calculated field `Sel` in your query. Are we missing a part of your code here?

Comment: The description of the desired action suggests that  'sel' is a parameter, not a calculated field.